# Whats the correct rule file to build to provide to the cppcheck MISRA add-on?

Tags: c, cppcheck, misra

This is a general question about the expected layout and content of a rule file to provide to the misra.py cppcheck application.

The cppcheck source located on github:
[source cppcheck](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/man/manual.md)

There are multiple ways I think?

```
Appendix A Summary of guidelines
Rule 1.1 
Rule text description
```

or is it

```
Appendix A Summary of guidelines
Rule 1.1 
Required:text description of the text
```

In the MISRA standard they talk about DIR 1.1 Rule 1.1
Required, mandatory, advisory.

The pdftotext and using the following method
[link to misra rule generator](https://github.com/ChisholmKyle/SublimeLinter-cppcheck-misra/blob/master/scripts/cppcheck-misra-parsetexts.py)
 I get only as output one dir 1.1

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit precious, but scraping a PDF to generate a text file of the Guideline headlines is surely a breach of the document licence agreement, and a breach of copyright too? Perhaps the correct approach is to ask MISRA nicely...

Answer (score 0):

The format of the rule file is listed in the usage/help output of the misra.py addon file located in cppcheck's GitHub repository. `python misra.py --help` outputs the usage section, although the newlines in the output is messed up in git bash and Windows command prompt for me making it less useful. The actual help text is nicely formatted in the [misra.py](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/7a009fece0f3812a69b3a79f9bc85d7f1a55b1a8/addons/misra.py#L3275-L3297) file though:

```
Format:
<..arbitrary text..>
Appendix A Summary of guidelines
Rule 1.1
Rule text for 1.1
Rule 1.2
Rule text for 1.2
<...>
```

I also tried to generate the rule file via the [misra rule generator](https://github.com/ChisholmKyle/SublimeLinter-cppcheck-misra/blob/master/scripts/cppcheck-misra-parsetexts.py) linked in the question. When running the generator in Windows using git bash (which has the `pdftotext` binary required by the script) I too only get the output file to contain a single entry (Dir 1.1 ). Running the generator in Ubuntu 18.04 it produces a large output file containing most of the Misra Rules and Directives. Git bash's `pdftotext` reports it's version 4.00 while the `pdftotext` in Ubuntu states 0.62.0. The output produces by `pdftotext` in Git Bash and Ubuntu is very different and the Misra rule generator script only works well with the output from Ubuntu's `pdftotext` in my case.

I also noted that the Misra rule generator has a bug which overwrites Rules and Directives having the same number. The output will not contain both Dir 1.1 and Rule 1.1, the last one parsed will overwrite the former due to a dictionary handling bug here [cppcheck-misra-parsetexts.py](https://github.com/ChisholmKyle/SublimeLinter-cppcheck-misra/blob/49959e06047bf894e55d95993a4d0fb2d4bcd3d0/scripts/cppcheck-misra-parsetexts.py#L69-L71)

Answer (score 0):

I modified [misra rule generator](https://github.com/ChisholmKyle/SublimeLinter-cppcheck-misra/blob/master/scripts/cppcheck-misra-parsetexts.py) which [elge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67620048/14246508) mentioned in his answer.
It doesn't overwrite Rules and Directives having the same number.
It also parses all the rules (generator mentioned above misses some of them).

Here is the link to [Modified MISRA guidelines generator](https://gist.github.com/bzgec/9ff8338f344d1a6a8dea4c50e2dbf54e).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34422407)

Comment: Ok, I understand. However, I'm not sure if it's appropriate to post 200 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

A reminder that the MISRA C is subject to copyright, and licencing restrictions!

However, MISRA C have released [a configuration file for CPPcheck](https://gitlab.com/MISRA/MISRA-C/MISRA-C-2012/tools/-/blob/main/misra_c_2023__headlines_for_cppcheck.txt), under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International ([CC BY-NC-ND 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/)) licence.

I respectfully request that this file is used, rather than those generated by various utilities that scrape the contents of the PDF.

--
Note: See profile for Affiliation